# How do I set the log levels for force:apex:log:tail?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, debug-logs

I'm in SFDX/VSCode, using the sfdx force:apex:log:tail command. That makes it easy to pull up the latest log, but when I try to launch the debugger, it says I need Apex at  FINEST and VisualForce at FINER. Where do I set that? Does it go in the cli command? Or is this in a json config file?

Or, do I go into my scratch org and set it there and then reference the name of that config?

UPDATE: I got it working by going into the dev console of the scratch org and creating a new debug level I called dx, then calling it in the cli. That seems like a roundabout way of doing it, so I think I'm probably missing something easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the debug level on the DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag for your user. It is written in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_log_tail):

> -d | --debuglevel DEBUGLEVEL
>
> Optional
>
> Debug level to set on the DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag for your user.
>
> Type: string

There's an example right below the command documentation:

```
$ sfdx force:apex:log:tail --debuglevel MyDebugLevel
```

So you set Apex to FINEST and Visualforce to FINE in MyDebugLevel in your org, and tell the command to use it.

> The --debuglevel parameter assigns a debug level to the active DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag.

As Thomas pointed out on the comments, it is possible to use the CLI to script this DebugLevel creation, using the `force:data:record:create` with the `-t | --usetoolingapi` parameter.

```
sfdx force:data:record:create -s DebugLevel -t -v "DeveloperName=From_CLI MasterLabel=From_CLI ApexCode=FINEST ApexProfiling=FINER Callout=DEBUG Database=Debug System=DEBUG Validation=FINE Visualforce=FINEST Workflow=WARN"
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs, but there are no examples of the command. Is it `-d='Apex=FINEST, VisualForce=FINER'`?

Comment: You should create the debug level and pass its name, if I understood correctly. I edited the post to add the example.

Comment: Thanks Renato. The real question I'm asking is where I set up 'MyDebugLevel' (to use your example.) I created one called 'dx' in the Dev Console of my scratch org, but that seems awkward. Is there a .json file in the sfdx project where that can be set? I literally need to know where I put 'Apex=FINEST' and 'VisualForce=FINER'. And if it goes into a json config file, which one? And if it doesn't exist in the project already, what is the format for it and where does it go?

Comment: That's the thing. Where the documentation states "debug level set on the trace flag for your user" it is actually saying that you should add it to your user on the platform. You are correct to do so using the developer console or the setup interface. As far as I know, there's no way to set/create it locally.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Sorry to seem so slow... just seems weird to go from the elegance of the cli  and json config files to the clunkiness of the dev console. I thought I was missing something easy.

Comment: You can use `sfdx force:data:record:create` with the `-t | --usetoolingapi` flag to create a DebugLevel (see [Tooling API docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_debuglevel.htm) for required fields and values). eg: `sfdx force:data:record:create -s DebugLevel -t -v "DeveloperName=From_CLI MasterLabel=From_CLI ApexCode=FINEST ApexProfiling=FINER Callout=DEBUG Database=Debug System=DEBUG Validation=FINE Visualforce=FINEST Workflow=WARN"` You'd want to script that - no option to pass a file.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor thanks! That's pretty wordy, but easy enough to create a BASH alias

Comment: This doesn't match what the "debug only" output checkbox does, which seems like the most common use case for this. What are the right settings for that?

Comment: Se all you don't want as "NONE", I guess.

Comment: Is there a way to set the current DebugLevel for tests?